# ruby- calculate concentric circle point

Tags: ruby, svg, graphics, geometry, trigonometry

[image]

I am calculating some geometry for concentric circles and a circle chord.

I need to take the radius length in green and create a corresponding shape with the (shorter) radius in orange.

Specifically, given the angle in red, the radius in green and the radius in orange, for the orange length's triangle I want to calculate the angle in pink.

I am working in ruby, but any general use of trig functions is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the radiuses of both concentric circles being `r` and `R` with `r < R` the pink angle is just `arccos(r/R)` assuming the defining triangle is rectangular as is seems to be in your picture. The red angle is not needed.

`Math.acos(r/R)` then gives you the angle in radian measure.

This is utterly trivial so I might be misunderstanding what you mean by "creat[ing] a corresponding shape".

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the radius of the outer circle (the green one) `ro`, and the radius of the inner circle (the orange one) `ri`, the red angle `alpha`, and the pink angle `beta`. It's easy to see that

ro * cos(beta) = ri * cos(alpha)

Thus `beta` can be easily resolved.

### Ruby code

beta = Math.acos(ri * Math.cos(alpha) / ro)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image above, it seems as though you know the adjacent and hypotenuse sides of the orange triangle. Ruby has a [nice Math module](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Math.html) that provides trigonometric functions. Check out the below:

```
hypotenuse_length = 5.0
adjacent_length = 3.0

red_angle = Math.acos(adjacent_length / hypotenuse_length)
print(Math.sin(red_angle) * hypotenuse_length)
# 4.0
```

In the event that you need degree values, you can extend `Numeric` to handle the conversions:

```
class Numeric
  def radians_to_degrees
    self * (180 / Math::PI)
  end

  def degrees_to_radians
    self * (Math::PI / 180) 
  end
end
```